# Pandas read csv dataframe rows from specific date and time range

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have a dataframe from CSV file as follows,

```
         TimeStamp
0        12/7/2017 8:00
1        12/7/2017 7:00
2        12/7/2017 6:00
3        12/7/2017 5:00
4        12/7/2017 4:00
5        12/7/2017 3:00
6        12/7/2017 2:00
7        12/7/2017 1:00
8        12/7/2017 0:00
9       11/7/2017 23:00
10      11/7/2017 22:00
...
9996     3/12/2015 6:00
9997     3/12/2015 5:00
9998     3/12/2015 4:00
9999     3/12/2015 3:00
Name: TimeStamp, Length: 10000, dtype: object
```

I am trying to use `Pandas` to read the data from a specific date and time range for example, from `11/7/2017 8:00` to `12/7/2017 8:00`.

I have tried using `Boolean mask`, `DatetimeIndex` and `.Between` methods and it read data out of that range and from 2016 and 2015 as well. Here are my codes,

```
import pandas as pd

eurusd = pd.read_csv('fxhistoricaldata_EURUSD_hour.csv')
eurusd = eurusd[(eurusd['TimeStamp'] >= '11/7/2017 8:00') & 
(eurusd['TimeStamp'] <= '12/7/2017 8:00')]

print(eurusd['TimeStamp'])
```

or using .between,

```
eurusd = eurusd[eurusd['TimeStamp'].between('11/7/2017 8:00', '12/7/2017 8:00')]
```

The results are as such,

```
2        12/7/2017 6:00
3        12/7/2017 5:00
4        12/7/2017 4:00
5        12/7/2017 3:00
6        12/7/2017 2:00
7        12/7/2017 1:00
8        12/7/2017 0:00
23       11/7/2017 9:00
24       11/7/2017 8:00
513     12/6/2017 23:00
514     12/6/2017 22:00
515     12/6/2017 21:00
516     12/6/2017 20:00
517     12/6/2017 19:00
518     12/6/2017 18:00
519     12/6/2017 17:00
520     12/6/2017 16:00
521     12/6/2017 15:00
522     12/6/2017 14:00
523     12/6/2017 13:00
524     12/6/2017 12:00
525     12/6/2017 11:00
         ...       
8827     12/2/2016 5:00
8828     12/2/2016 4:00
8829     12/2/2016 3:00
Name: TimeStamp, Length: 305, dtype: object
```

Can anyone help me rectify my problem or are there any function that can help me fulfill my task? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: convert the timestamp column like `eurusd['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(eurusd['Timestamp'])` and your solution will work.

Comment: or use parse_dates=True for read_csv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to Ensure `eurusd['TimeStamp']` is a series with dtype `datetime64[ns]`:

```
eurusd['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(eurusd['TimeStamp'])
```

Create a boolean mask:

```
mask = (eurusd['TimeStamp'] > start_date) & (eurusd['TimeStamp'] <= end_date)
```

Now, Re-assign (or whatever you want to do with the output):

```
eurusd = eurusd.loc[mask]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the datetime and dateutil libraries:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

df['TimeStamp'] = df['TimeStamp'].apply(lambda x: parser.parse(x))

df[(df['TimeStamp'] < datetime(2017, 12, 7)) & (df['TimeStamp']> datetime(2015, 3, 12))] #or whichever dates you're looking for
```